# DateTime.ParseExact error

Tags: parsing, datetime

if I have a date in a text field as follows 2012-09-27T11:41:16:587Z

how would I do the ParseExact?

I think I am close with
                DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
but it errors out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange no-one answered this. This will work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, @"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss:fff\Z",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Compared to your format string, the only difference is that I included `"fff"` for the milliseconds, and I put in `@"\T"` and `@"\Z"` to deal with the letters T and Z in your `date` string.

Comment: Yes I wrote that line of code a few months back and am not sure what I did but I did get it working and I think it was the missing T and Z and probably the fff lol I had a lot missing but I am up to speed on customizing date fields now after that.  I do appreciate your reply sir!